# After changing the root password, why does my user sudo login is failing?

Tags: 12.04

change the root password.
try to execute the command with sudo, it fails to execute with new root password.
Is there any command we need to run, after changing the root password, in order to sudo to work.

Answer (score 3):

The password that you enter when doing the `sudo` command is not the root password, it's the password of the user executing the `sudo` command. So, if you're logged in as a user `uday`, and you do `sudo <command>`, you'll be asked to enter the password of the account `uday`, not the root password. Take a look at this:

```
uday@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /media/test
[sudo] password for uday:
```

Notice that it says `password for uday`.

So if your intention was to change the password that you enter when you use `sudo`, then change the password of your account, not the root password.

Since you've set a root password, the root account has now been unlocked and enabled to login. It is usually advisable against that. So, unless you really need the root account, you can **d**elete its password and **l**ock it and by issuing the following command:

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

If you want to read more information about `root` and `sudo`, visit [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) page.

Comment: You're welcome. It is advisable **not** to set a root password unless you really need to, because setting a root password unlocks the account and enables its login. If you are not going to be using the root account, I suggest you lock it. I've edited my answer on how to do that. Also, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) when you can.